# Import maven project from github to Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I tried to import [this](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java) project into Intellij IDEA in the [following](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bud6BXb_53c) way (00:38 - 00:57 are only relevant for me in this video).

After that, at the "project" explorer I went to "src -> test -> java" , and right clicked on "run all tests" . I got many errors of not finding class symbols - which seems that are related to dependecies problem.

I didn't understand why I'm getting these errors. Maybe there is something that I need to install which doesn't appear in this video?

Comment: Which errors did you get?

Comment: "Cannot find symbol" . Got it for a lot of classes

Comment: did you enable the auto-import function? (there should have been a pop-up), also could you try to do a 'mvn package'

Comment: @Stephan, do you mean "import maven project automotically" (like in 00:46 in the video)?

Comment: in this case the answer is no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to build the project from terminal with `mvn clean package` first, and then reopen intelliJ.